# Flutter - Rendering a HTML Unordered List

Tags: html, flutter, dart

I’m trying to represent HTML code in Flutter (**ul** to be specific) and minimally style it. I tried using the **flutter_html** package, and I see there’s a customRender option.

Basically, what I’m trying to do:

- Add a space under every **li** element.
- Take away the left margin (it's there by default on flutter_html).
- Change the color of the bullet point. Not, necessary, but would be nice.

I'm pretty new to Flutter and Dart, so I can't manage to make the customRender work. Perhaps someone knows how to go around it? Or maybe there's a better way to do it?

---

Adding some code fore reference.

```dart
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';

// ... Some non-essential code ...

Align(
  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
  child: Html(
    data: """${unorderedList}""",
    customRender: (node, children) {
      if (node is dom.Element) {
        switch (node.localName) {
          case "li":
            return Column(children: children);
        }
      }
      return null;
    },
  )
)
```

Note: taking out the **customRender** block produces a left margin.

---

EDIT: Addition to the **vb10** solution that allows multiline list item texts.

```dart
Wrap customListItem(dom.Element node) {
  return Wrap(
    spacing: 25.0,
    children: [
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, 
        children: [
          Padding(
            // Top padding adjusts for text offset, set it to the font size.
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0, right: 15.0), 
            child: CircleAvatar(radius: 4)
          ),
          Expanded(child: Text(node.text)),
        ]
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 25.0),
    ]
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Edited. The input for the HTML is just a regular <ul> with a bunch of <li>. The list or the list items don't have any attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't forget two rules:

- You can create custom widget so rich-text set to false (default True)
- You have custom widget options need page margin like item spacing.

Look at this code:

```
 Html(
    data: data,
    useRichText: false,
    customRender: htmlCustomRenderer,
  )
```

[image]

If you detail look at [this](https://github.com/VB10/stack-over-help-flutter).(lib/html-parser)

Result: [image]

Comment: It's nearly exactly what I was looking for! But it seems that the Wrap widget forces the node.text to jump to the next line if it spans more than one line. Perhaps there's a widget that would work better in this case?

Comment: This situation, need a test case. if you have more line, you need custom parser method but more advanced. I think you can have more line, fix the HTML body on the backend side after sending fix body.

Comment: Managed to fix it with Rows and Expanded and playing around with some padding.

Answer (score 2):

The package has been updated (v1.0.0) and it has been changed but it's now easier to do:

```
Html(
  data: {html}
  customRender: {
    "li": (RenderContext context, Widget child, attributes, dom.Element element) {
      return this.customListItem(element);
     },
  },
),
```

```
Wrap customListItem(dom.Element node) {
  return Wrap(
    crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
    spacing: 4,
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
        child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 2,
        ),
      ),
      Text(node.text)
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add dom as dom to get access to element:      `import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;`